# How to apply changes on selected columns for multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am aggregating selected column values of a data frame df, say

```
        LoB cc   AY AQ age inj_part Pay00 Pay01 Pay02 Pay03 Pay04 Pay05 Pay06 Pay07 Pay08 Pay09 Pay10 Pay11
1603528   1  1 1997  1  15       10   573     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2135181   1  1 1999  1  15       10   439     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3005060   1  1 2001  1  15       10    46     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3140988   1  1 2001  1  15       10   349     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4280242   1  1 2004  1  15       10   345     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4992637   1  1 2005  1  15       10   811     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

through implementing

```
df[7:18] <- do.call("cbind", Reduce(`+`, df[7:18], accumulate = TRUE))
```

so that

```
        LoB cc   AY AQ age inj_part Pay00 Pay01 Pay02 Pay03 Pay04 Pay05 Pay06 Pay07 Pay08 Pay09 Pay10 Pay11
1603528   1  1 1997  1  15       10   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573
2135181   1  1 1999  1  15       10   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439
3005060   1  1 2001  1  15       10    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46
3140988   1  1 2001  1  15       10   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349
4280242   1  1 2004  1  15       10   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345
4992637   1  1 2005  1  15       10   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811
```

I have several dfs like this (contained in list df_list) and I've been using `lapply()` to apply other changes on each of them in the following format

```
result <- lapply(df_list, \(x) ...)
```

However, I am finding it hard to figure out how to only apply the changes on columns 7:18 of these dfs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the same code with `x` being the individual dataset, subset the columns with `Pay` prefix (in the updated data), use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`, assign it back, and return the data `x`

```
result <- lapply(df_list, \(x)  {
           nm <- grep("^Pay", names(x))
           x[nm] <-do.call("cbind", Reduce(`+`, x[nm], accumulate = TRUE))
           x
        })
```

-output

```
result
$`1.1.1.15.10`
        LoB cc   AY AQ age inj_part Pay00 Pay01 Pay02 Pay03 Pay04 Pay05 Pay06 Pay07 Pay08 Pay09 Pay10 Pay11
1603528   1  1 1997  1  15       10   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573
2135181   1  1 1999  1  15       10   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439
3005060   1  1 2001  1  15       10    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46
3140988   1  1 2001  1  15       10   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349
4280242   1  1 2004  1  15       10   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345
4992637   1  1 2005  1  15       10   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811

$`2.1.1.15.10`
        LoB cc   AY AQ age inj_part Pay00 Pay01 Pay02 Pay03 Pay04 Pay05 Pay06 Pay07 Pay08 Pay09 Pay10 Pay11
434863    2  1 1995  1  15       10  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046
923365    2  1 1996  1  15       10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1225196   2  1 1996  1  15       10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4295570   2  1 2004  1  15       10   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
result <- map(df_list, ~ .x %>%
           # or use pick in newer version
           # mutate(pick(starts_with("Pay")) %>%
            mutate(across(starts_with("Pay")) %>%
                      accumulate(`+`) %>%
                      bind_cols))
```

-output

```
result
$`1.1.1.15.10`
        LoB cc   AY AQ age inj_part Pay00 Pay01 Pay02 Pay03 Pay04 Pay05 Pay06 Pay07 Pay08 Pay09 Pay10 Pay11
1603528   1  1 1997  1  15       10   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573   573
2135181   1  1 1999  1  15       10   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439   439
3005060   1  1 2001  1  15       10    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46    46
3140988   1  1 2001  1  15       10   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349   349
4280242   1  1 2004  1  15       10   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345   345
4992637   1  1 2005  1  15       10   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811   811

$`2.1.1.15.10`
        LoB cc   AY AQ age inj_part Pay00 Pay01 Pay02 Pay03 Pay04 Pay05 Pay06 Pay07 Pay08 Pay09 Pay10 Pay11
434863    2  1 1995  1  15       10  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046  4046
923365    2  1 1996  1  15       10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1225196   2  1 1996  1  15       10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4295570   2  1 2004  1  15       10   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375   375
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! However, I am encountering

Error in do.call("cbind", Reduce(`+`, x[4:9], accumulate = TRUE)) : 
  second argument must be a list

from the first code and on the second

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(4:9) %>% accumulate(`+`) %>% bind_cols`.
✖ `..1` must be size 1, not 6.

I think they are referring to the same error. Can you help me deal with them?

Comment: Here is str(df_list[[1]]) from my actual data
'data.frame': 6 obs. of  18 variables

Comment: It works perfectly fine with the reproducible example data you provided.

Comment: @JGM Can you update your post with the `dput(df_list[1:2])`, it must be related to the structure

Comment: Sorry, I am actually new to programming. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, I used 7:18 on my actual code, but presented sample df for 4:9 for simplicity.

Comment: @JGM Does the update works for you?